# Show AlertDialog in IntentService

Tags: android, android-context, android-intentservice

How to show AlertDialog in IntentService? Error looks like:
Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application.
So this is problem with context, but I don't know how to fix it. Any solutions?
Below there is my code:

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends IntentService {

private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
private static AlertDialog alert;

String mes;
private Handler handler;
public GcmMessageHandler() {
    super("GcmMessageHandler");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    handler = new Handler();

}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    mes = extras.getString("message");
    MApp.wakeupSync();

    showToast();
    Log.i("GCM", "Received : (" + messageType + ")  " + extras.getString("message"));
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        gcm.unregister();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void showToast(){

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            builder.setMessage("TEST")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: I think the only thing you can do, is to start an activity which shows your dialog. You could make the background of the activity transparent.

Comment: Return result to from where u have started.

Comment: Show activity as dialog, <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />

Comment: My way is to StartNotification, send value using braodcast to intent, and show alert in the intent

Answer (score 1):

You can only show AlertDialog using Activity context.

Here you use getApplicationContext() to create builder, but
neither Application context nor Service context will work.
You have to send broadcast/intent to some Activity and as a response to this message show an AlertDialog inside this Activity using Activity context.

Read this for more details:
https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

Comment: My way is to StartNotification, send value using braodcast to intent, and show alert in the intent

Comment: I don't get exactly what do you mean by "show alert in the intent"
The main point here is not to use getApplicationContext() it can't work.
Use any Activity context instead.

Comment: AlertDialog in the Activity which is selected in Notification

Answer (score 0):

Define a handler in your `Activity`

```
    /**
     * Response handler
     */
    private Handler handlerResponse = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         //Show your alert here
       }
   };
```

Start service along with `Messenger`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CommunicationService.class);
 intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_ONE);
 intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_MESSENGER, new Messenger(handlerResponse));
 startService(intent);
```

In your service return the message after completing the functionality

```
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
           sendResult(intent, result);
        }
     }

private void sendResult(Intent intent, String result) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Messenger messenger = (Messenger) extras.get(Constants.EXTRA_MESSENGER);
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.obj = result;
            try {
                messenger.send(msg);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Exception sending message", e1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Constants

```
 public static final String EXTRA_MESSENGER = "EXTRA_MESSENGER";
 public static final String ACTION_ONE = "INIT_SOCKET";
```

Comment: My way is to StartNotification, send value using braodcast to intent, and show alert in the intent